# iAutoLayout crash when setting Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiview, autolayout

HI I am setting my views using autoLayouts with visual format language.

I add some constraints to my views.

Here are my codes how I set up:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
self.first  = [UIView new];
self.second = [UIView new];
self.third  = [UIView new];
self.fourth = [UIView new];
self.fifth  = [UIView new];

self.first.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
self.second.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.third.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;
self.fourth.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
self.fifth.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = NO;

[self.view addSubview:self.first];
[self.view addSubview:self.second];
[self.view addSubview:self.third];
[self.view addSubview:self.fourth];
[self.view addSubview:self.fifth];

NSDictionary *dictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth);

NSArray *constraintsArray;
NSString *format;

format = @"|[_first][_second][_third][_fourth][_fifth]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|[_first]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|[_second]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|[_third]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|[_fourth]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

format = @"V:|[_fifth]|";
constraintsArray = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft metrics:nil views:dictionary];
[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];

}
```

Here is what i want the five `UIView`s act as. They have same **WIDTH and HEIGHT** and there are **no margin** on both size.(The first one and the last one) . That's say, they are filled within there container view, in this case, (self.view)

[image]

When I run, the app crash:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unable to parse   constraint format: 
Options mask required views to be aligned on a horizontal edge, which is not allowed for layout that is also horizontal. 
|[_first][_second][_third][_fourth][_fifth]| 
                  ^'
```

What I had done wrong? 
Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should remove all of those references to `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft`.

Also, unrelated, but you are missing the constraint that makes them the same width. I'd replace the horizontal constraint with:

```
format = @"H:|[_first][_second(==_first)][_third(==_first)][_fourth(==_first)][_fifth(==_first)]|";
```

Comment: Thanks Rob,  and `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft` should replace with what? you mean nil?

Comment: kNilOptions didn't work Rob, where did you find that constant and what is it supposed to be set to?

Comment: In Objective-C, `kNilOptions` is a standard constant used where multiple options are accepted in Cocoa API. But I'm guessing from your question that you're using Swift, in which case you now use `[]` in Swift 2 and later.

Answer (score 1):

format string proposed by Rob is perfect. You can also avoid all the other vertical constraints just adding 'NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop' instead of 'NSLayoutFormatAlignAllLeft'.
Basically when you deal with a format string related to horizontal axis you must use alignment options that relate to vertical axis and vice versa ( option is perpendicular to format string ), or if you don't need it just pass 0.
Your only one method should look like this:

```
NSString format = @"H:|[_first][_second(==_first)][_third(==_first)][_fourth(==_first)][_fifth(==_first)]|";

[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format 
                                        options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                                        metrics:nil
                                          views:dictionary];
```

[EDIT]

Rob's right. NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop aligns all top side of views inside the format string between them and not to their superview. You have to add one vertical pin constraint to only one of your view and all the others will also align because of 'NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop'. Also to remove ambiguous layout you need to add a height constraint. This is the code i tried (with a 100 point height) and doesn't give me ambiguous layout:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(_first, _second, _third, _fourth, _fifth);


NSString *format = @"H:|[_first][_second(==_first)][_third(==_first)][_fourth(==_first)][_fifth(==_first)]|";

NSMutableArray *constraintsArray =  [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:format
                                                                           options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop
                                                                           metrics:nil
                                                                             views:dictionary].mutableCopy;

[constraintsArray addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_first
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                            toItem:_first.superview
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                        multiplier:1.0 constant:0]];

CGFloat height = 100;

for (UIView *view in @[_first,_second,_third,_fourth,_fifth]) {
    [constraintsArray addObject:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:view
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                             relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                                toItem:nil
                                                             attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                            multiplier:1.0
                                                              constant:height]];


}


[self.view addConstraints:constraintsArray];
```

Comment: That's say, I don't need to set constraint in vertical for each one if i use `NSLayoutFormatAlignAllTop` ?

Comment: In this specific example yes, you can delete all the other methods because this option as it says align all the view to the top.

Comment: Thanks your advice, Cesare, i will improve my code.:)

Comment: If you want to master Autolayout in code I suggest you reading 'Autolayout demystified' by Erica Sadun. It's a wonderful book about this topic

Comment: @Wong I don't think you can't get rid of the vertical constraints, though, because you still need to set the bottom constraint. Bottom line, try it and then run the app, pause execution, and at the `(lldb)` prompt, enter `po [[UIWindow keyWindow] _autolayoutTrace]`. That will tell you if your constraints are ambiguous or not.

Comment: I added some code to my answer to correct ambiguous layout issue.